# Optmization and tuning Linux Server (Mediaserver)

Tags: linux, networking, performance, disk, optimization

I rebuilt a server, specifically a mediaserver, based on **debian 12** stable (kernel **6.1**).

- **CPU**: **i7-6700K**(no overclock)
- **RAM**: 16GB DDR4 (dual channel)
- **NIC**: 2 of 2.5Gbit (bonding **balance-tlb**) (**MTU** bond0: 4096. But my network home have classic MTU)
- **GPU**: PHY T400 (4gb version)
- **STORAGE**: 3 **SSD**

These SSDs are configured like this:

1. **SSD1**: 1TB per film (**xfs**) (scheduler: **none**)
2. **SSD2**: 250GB for the OS (**125GB** OS, 125GB for swap) (**ext4**) (scheduler: **none**)

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 232,89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcfa6d02d

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         2048 244140031 244137984 116,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       244140032 488280063 244140032 116,4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Filesystem volume name:   root
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          927a3648-60d1-4537-af56-0d87ff5a6e0b
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index fast_commit filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              7634944
Block count:              30517248
Reserved block count:     305172
Overhead clusters:        625720
Free blocks:              28139695
Free inodes:              7541676
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Oct 17 02:41:54 2023
Last mount time:          Thu Oct 19 19:21:21 2023
Last write time:          Thu Oct 19 19:21:21 2023
Mount count:              25
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Oct 18 03:33:16 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          90 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      5f52b9e5-cf5a-438c-9e90-0c2d91207ea7
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x2f208f9b
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3 FEATURE_I5
Total journal size:       512M
Total journal blocks:     131072
Max transaction length:   130816
Fast commit length:       256
Journal sequence:         0x0000796d
Journal start:            1
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x0a6d11a2
```

3. **SSD3**: 500GB for the "general" cache (transcoding, cache for network mount points via fscache, etc). (**ext4**) (scheduler: **none**)

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: CT500MX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

dumpe2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /cache
Filesystem UUID:          070d06bd-6a01-4457-b20f-cf699f412168
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index fast_commit filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              30531584
Block count:              122096646
Reserved block count:     0
Overhead clusters:        2201430
Free blocks:              119895208
Free inodes:              30531569
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed Oct 18 19:01:18 2023
Last mount time:          Thu Oct 19 19:21:22 2023
Last write time:          Thu Oct 19 19:21:22 2023
Mount count:              16
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Oct 18 19:01:18 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          48 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      cbad2af6-a244-4e66-b27c-3e8dea9f8f2f
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x47fb58ba
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3 FEATURE_I5
Total journal size:       1040M
Total journal blocks:     266240
Max transaction length:   262144
Fast commit length:       4096
Journal sequence:         0x00000384
Journal start:            0
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0xae89c35f
```

Softwares used: **Plex** (with **HW** transcoding/encoding) and **Serviio**(DLNA Software)

I chose xfs as the filesystem for the films as large files will be hosted (and it is well known that xfs performs on this type of file), for all the other SSDs I chose ext4, also for the cache. Did I make a correct choice?
Small premise: do not look at this server/storage associated with a backup plan, data security regarding the filesystem, etc. as this server only acts as a "passage"... let me explain better... that is, it must give its best regarding transcoding, speed of access to files (via cifs/fscache) and everything related to file sharing medium, so even if something were to be damaged I wouldn't lose anything... I don't know if I've gotten the idea. So I look for optimizations/settings to speed it up as much as possible, including throughput. I posted some configurations. According to a more expert opinion, should I change/add something? Leaving aside these configurations, should I change something in the OS too? I only have rsyslogd running, leaving out the software mentioned above that I mainly use.

**grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet mitigations=off nopti net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=1 i915.enable_psr=0 i915.enable_dc=0 zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lzo nowatchdog nosgx"
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
kernel.sysrq=0
vm.swappiness=1
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=60

fs.suid_dumpable=0
kernel.core_pattern=|/bin/false

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=5
net.ipv4.tcp_sack=1
net.core.default_qdisc=cake
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=bbr
```